# Inline annotation for angular controller (services)

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, angular-fullstack

I am using the generator-angular-fullstack for my app and have come into a problem when minifying / uglyfying my code.

Before minifying my code i could use services and they would work fine but afterwards i get the following error:

[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

I read that i need to add inline annotations to my controller like this (to stop the minify process from destroying the service:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'HOORAY!'; 
}]);
```

generator-angular-fullstack creates controllers like this:

```
(function () {

    class EmployeesearchComponent {

        constructor($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, elasticservice, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.message = 'HOORAY!'; 
        };
    }

    angular.module('myApp')
        .component('employeesearch', {

            templateUrl: 'app/employeesearch/employeesearch.html',
            controller: EmployeesearchComponent

        });

})();
```

Where am i supposed to add the services as strings?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the strings above the constructor field:

static $inject = ['$scope', '$http']

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change the `controller` key to have an array with the parameters' names and the controller class at the end, like so:

```
[...]

.component('employeesearch', {
  controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'elasticservice', '$mdDialog', EmployeesearchComponent]    
});
```

But you should really think about adding these annotations during your build process, it would make you code cleaner. If you're using build systems like *gulp* or *grunt* there are libraries that allow you to do this just by adding a single extra line to your build script. You can find it as "ng-annotate".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, adding to the controller is what i wanted to do like you demonstrated (thanks). I already use ng-annotate during the build process which has always worked well - i had an issue where one of the services wasnt working correctly after being built so i wanted to explicitly set it as a string to make sure it wasnt the build process messing it up. Thanks again